# Attempting to load Webview with PDF, receiving link from Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, xcode6.3

I am attempting to load a lunch menu PDF into a web view for a high school app that I am updating. Currently, it can load a PDF into the web view and display it just fine, but I want to speed up the monthly update process by having my app receive the link through Parse (Which I can update much quicker than updating the link in the app itself with Apple's 7 day review period), and then load the PDF. Currently, with what I have put together, my app will not load the PDF. Here's the entire view:

```
import UIKit

class AlaCarte_ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var webviewAlaCarte: UIWebView!

var urlpath = String()

func loadAddressUrl(){


    let requestURL = NSURL (string:urlpath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webviewAlaCarte.loadRequest(request)

    alaCarteUpdate()

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    clearPDFBackground(self.webviewAlaCarte)



}

func clearPDFBackground(webView: UIWebView) {
    var view :UIView?
    view = webView as UIView

    while view != nil {
        if NSStringFromClass(view?.dynamicType) == "UIWebPDFView" {
            view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        }

        view = view?.subviews.first as! UIView?

    }
}

func alaCarteUpdate() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "AlaCarte")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("rT7MpEFySU") {(AlaCarte: PFObject!, error: NSError!)-> Void in
        if error == nil && AlaCarte != nil {
            println(AlaCarte)
        } else {
            println(error)
        }

        let AlaCarteLink = AlaCarte["webaddress"] as! String

        self.urlpath = AlaCarteLink

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadAddressUrl()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

The link is stored in my Parse app as "webaddress" and does not contain end quotations. Adding them does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're not telling the web view to load the URL once it's retrieved from Parse.

Try adding the following lines after `self.urlpath = AlaCarteLink` in `alaCarteUpdate()`.

```
let requestURL = NSURL (string:self.urlpath)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
self.webviewAlaCarte.loadRequest(request)
```

I think it would also be a good idea to add a function that specifically loads a url string into your web view, so you can call it from both inside `alaCarteUpdate()`, and `loadAddressUrl()`, and avoid the duplicate 3x lines. I've assumed that you're loading the URL in `loadAddressURL()` so that you can show a local/cached document while retrieving the latest from Parse.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly- I definitely can clean it up a little bit though.